# Why does these two WFS layers fail to render in QGIS?

Tags: gis, qgis, wfs

I tried to download the layers "River U Lancang","River Maintrib", and "Main River Line" in the following WFS server: https://geo.mrcmekong.org/geoserver/wms?service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities

Every other layer works, but these three layers throw back the following error:

```
2022-03-08T16:29:54     WARNING    Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1, column 720
2022-03-08T16:29:54     WARNING    Retrying request https://geo.mrcmekong.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=mrc:River U Lancang&SRSNAME=EPSG:32648&OUTPUTFORMAT=GML3: 2/3
2022-03-08T16:29:56     WARNING    Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1, column 720
2022-03-08T16:29:56     WARNING    Retrying request https://geo.mrcmekong.org/geoserver/wms
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is using an invalid namespace `mrc:River U Lancang gml:id="River U Lancang.1">` - You can't use spaces here. I think the only solution is to contact the owner of the service and ask them to fix this.